# How to share code between jobs in Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action pipeline with multiple jobs, and each job has its own checkout step. But I am not sure if this can have some side effects.
What happens when there is another commit when my pipeline is already running? Will my pipeline run then checkout the changes from the other commit?
How can I avoid this? Should I use "actions/cache" instead of checkout the code in every step? Or is "actions/upload-artifact" and "actions/download-artifacts" better? Or maybe a totally different solution?

Example of my pipeline

```
name: my_job

on: [push]

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - uses: actions/setup-java@3
      with:
        distribution: 'adopt'
        java-version: '17'
        cache: 'maven'

    - name: test
      run: ./mvnw clean verify

    - name: build
      run: ./mvnw package

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: infrastructure
      run: ./script/infrastructure.sh

    - name: deploy app
      run: ./script/delploy_app.sh
```

Comment: Why are you using two jobs? You can set if conditions between steps and you haven’t to worry about sharing data between jobs. To avoid multiple job runs with further commits take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512537/16452810
If you want to use multiple jobs we‘ve used artifacts to share data between them.